# How to hint to typescript that a string is consistent across multiple indexing operations

Tags: typescript, types

Minimal example of the problem:

```
const a = {
    'x': {},
    'y': 'y',
};
const b = {
    'x': {},
    'y': 'y',
};
for (const p of ['x', 'y'] as const) {
    a[p] = b[p]; // error string | {} is not assignable to {} & string
}
for (const p of ['x', 'y'] as const) {
    switch (p) {
        case 'x':
            a[p] = b[p]; // no error
            break;
        case 'y':
            a[p] = b[p]; // no error
            break;
    }
}
```

Typescript sees the type of `p` as `'x' | 'y'` but doesn't correlate the fact that `a` and `b` are being indexed by the same value.

Is there a way to... distribute? the union operation so that essentially the typed expression becomes goes from `a['x'|'y'] = b['x'|'y']` to `a['x'] = b['x'] | a['y'] = b['y']`

I've tried generic functions and a host of attempts at coercing the types of the inputs but short of asserting `as any` nothing seems to work.

I'd like to avoid type `as` assertions (especially to `any`) as it adds one more area where type analysis is likely to fail, but I feel like I don't have any other options other than generating code during build but that's a rather large additional build step I'd rather not add for something that feels small like this.

A switch statement isn't a feasible alternative since the actual number of keys is much larger than 2 and is liable to change so this would involve adding many sections of duplicated code throughout my codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of a [type safety improvement to indexed access types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types) introduced in TypeScript 3.5, as implemented by [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769).  In general it is unsafe to allow `a[p] = b[q]` where `a` and `b` are of the same object type and where `p` and `q` are of the same union type, since if `p` and `q` turn out to be different elements of the union, you might be writing an incompatible value.  In your case you are doing `a[p] = b[p]`, but from the type system's perspective that's the same thing; all it sees is that you are writing and reading an object property whose key is a union type `"x" | "y"`, which is unsafe in general.  It doesn't pay attention to the fact that if you're using the exact same value `p` in both places, then it has to be safe.

So since TypeScript 3.5 this has been a pain point. There is a request to fix this for when you are reading or writing the "same" property; see [microsoft/TypeScript#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693).  And, fortunately, according to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693#issuecomment-598860475) it looks like this will be fixed for the case here where you're literally using the same identifier (like `p`) as the key.  Not sure when that will happen, though... the issue seems to be on the Backlog and not slated for a particular release of TypeScript.  So it could be a while.

---

Until then it should be possible to refactor to a generic function, since one place they still allow the older pre-TS-3.5 unsafe access is when you are using generic type.  This is mentioned in a [comment on #30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559):

> One rule we've always had is that any given type (and, by extension, any `T[K]` for identical `T` and `K`) is by definition assignable to itself, and that's the basic unsoundness we permit

So if we introduce this indirection:

```
function copyProp<T, K extends keyof T>(dst: T, src: T, key: K) {
    dst[key] = src[key];
}
```

That compiles just fine, and now we can use it:

```
for (const p of ['x', 'y'] as const) {
    copyProp(a, b, p);
}
```

which also compiles without error.  It's annoying, but at least there is a solution/workaround that works for now, at least until a fix for #32693 is released.

---

One last thought about wishing this could be fixed in general so you could avoid switch statements.  A while ago I opened a feature request [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051) to allow for "opt-in distributive control flow analysis" where you could say something like `type switch (p) {...}` and have the compiler evaluate the enclosed code block once for each element of the union type of `p`, and if each pass succeeded, then the whole thing would succeed.  The compiler feasibly can't do that kind of multi-pass analysis for each union-typed expression it encounters, but I was hoping we could at least have some syntax to ask for it in specific cases.  Alas, it is not to be (and was closed as a duplicate of one of the several issues it would address), but when I see this issue I become wistful and [think of what might have been...](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-500543013).  Sigh...

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gWAFA2zA5AD1wC5UBfAGkxzwE9jbdKNSBuTUSWAIyVSpwL0UFftlx0S4xplaZMAMwCuYYFACW4GKAAONAAoAnENoA8AFXIwA0jACm+KLbAATCDADWtmiHkwzAPgAKVygSCxgIA2Awy08aEisASj4sHBCAbTiAXV5I4EyvLLZmOQx5EAMYQI5oGG0YHxh0wUspHLg3Gqhk9FTsHX0jbUC4Sy5LbUTi0lKqIA)

Comment: Thank you! I wish there was a better way, but it seems that the typescript devs are intent on restricting the scope of their type system.  It might be a good decision from a maintainability perspective but it's certainly frustrating to encounter the limitations so often.